# python unittest prevent abstract testBase class test itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

**What I have:**

I have a `TestBase.py` that I am using as an abstract test class.

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class TestBase:

    expectData = None

    def test_check_expectData(self):
        if self.expectData is None:
            raise NotImplementedError('you must have expectData')

    @abstractmethod
    def test_command_OK(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses must override test_command()!')
```

I want others to inherite `TestBase`. for Example `TestDemo.py`

```
import unittest
from TestBase import TestBase

class TestDemo(unittest.TestCase, TestBase):

    expectData = ["someData"]

    def test_command_OK(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I run `python TestDemo.py` everything works as expected. If I don't have a expectedDate I will get a `NotImplementedError` and if I don't have a `test_command_OK` method I get a `NotImplementedError: subclasses must override test_command()!`

**Problem:**

when I run the test suite from setup.py `python setup.py test` things break. The reason I think setup.py is running the `TestBase` class on its own and in `TestBase` class `expectedData` is `None` so it fails the test.

```
====================================================================== ERROR: myProject.tests.TestDemo.TestBase.test_check_expectData
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)   File "/Users/z002x6m/Desktop/myProject/tests/TestBase.py", line 49, in test_check_expectData
    if self.expectData is None: AttributeError: TestBase instance has no attribute 'expectData'
====================================================================== ERROR: myProject.tests.TestDemo.TestBase.test_command_OK
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)   File "/Users/z002x6m/Desktop/myProject/tests/TestBase.py", line 57, in test_command_OK
    raise NotImplementedError('subclasses must override test_command()!') NotImplementedError: subclasses must override test_command()!
```

If I print out `print(self.__class__)` in my `test_check_expectData(self)` method I get `<class '__main__.TestDemo'>` when I run TestDemo directly which is when everything works fine. I get `myProject.tests.TestDemo.TestBase`when I run `python setup.py test`.

Is there a way for me to tell `setup.py` not to run `TestBase` class? maybe `@unittest.skipis , @unittest.skipif, @unittest.skipunless`? but I don't want the subclass to skip these require tests beacuse I want all subclass to have expectData. TestBase is meant to be use as a template and force/check sub test classes have all the requirements such as `expectData`. but it shouldn't be run on it own. What can I do to get pass this issue? I don't mind suggestions even if it means to restrucutre my current test framework

Comment: "things break". Not good enough. Post a full stack trace. Right now it looks like you are just guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: when I say things break all test failed. you are right let me edit my post

Comment: Format console output as code please. I'm on mobile so can't help with that.

Comment: What about `if self.__class__ != TestBase and self.expectData is None:`?

Comment: I tried that before but it doesn't work. `self.__class__ = myProject.tests.TestDemo.TestBase` and `TestBase = myProject.tests.TesBase.TestBase` when I run `python setup.py test` and since they are not the same  the test would still run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, use SkipTest would skip the test if subclass `super()` the `TestBase` class

```
from unittest.case import SkipTest

    def test_check_expectData(self):
        if self.expectData is None:
            raise SkipTest
```